# Warnings during curl request

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting the following error when doing a curl request with a magento observer( after the user has entered all payment info etc). Ive already tried all the common remedies to these errors such as removing whitespaces before and after php tags, and explicitly, typecasting the foreach array...to no avail. for some reason its also showing the post paramaters on the user page itself( which it should not!)

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/Api.php

Line Number: 68

Backtrace:

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/application/controllers/Api.php
 Line: 68
 Function: _error_handler

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
 Line: 708
 Function: call_user_func_array

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/index.php
 Line: 315
 Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/philip/public_html/collector/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 568

Backtrace:

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
 Line: 785
 Function: set_status_header

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
 Line: 818
 Function: response

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/application/controllers/Api.php
 Line: 90
 Function: set_response

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
 Line: 708
 Function: call_user_func_array

File: /home2/philip/public_html/collector/index.php
 Line: 315
 Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't disable any error on your production system.
Add this to your php.ini

> error_reporting = off

Your specific error Message looks to me like you try to foreach through a Variable which isn't an Array. Becaus of this, you see the first error and because the first error has an output, you got the second error.

try this before your foreach

```
if (!is_array($YOURARRAY)) {
    return;
}
```